# Microsoft Word VBA script to accept all deletions?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I work with a lot of revisions in Word 2010 (multiple authors with track changes on).  I'd like to create a way to accept all deletions in a document without accepting the insertions.  I did some research and found a VBA script example that claimed to do this but it just gave me an error message.  It was a couple weeks ago and I can't find the script or remember the error message.

Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks in advance.

### *SOLUTION:*

Found the code I was using and for some reason it's working now.

```
Sub AcceptDeletion()
Dim oChange As Revision
For Each oChange In ActiveDocument.Revisions
  With oChange
   If .Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
     .Accept
   End If
  End With
Next oChange
End Sub
```

Comment: What error message? The code works fine as is.

Answer (score 2):

You could be more tidy if for :

```
With oChange
   If .Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
     .Accept
   End If
End With
```

you were to say:

```
If oChange.Type = wdRevisionDelete Then oChange.Accept
```

Comment: I get "Object has been deleted" when running

If .Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
but trying to compare it to Nothing doesn't work as well. Any way around this? Object has been deleted

Answer (score 0):

The script above kept throwing an "Object has been deleted" error at me because the collection was modified during the loop. This one worked for me:

```
Sub AcceptDeletions()
Dim oChange As Revision
For i = ActiveDocument.Revisions.Count To 1 Step -1
If ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Accept
End If
Next i
End Sub
```