# Requested Object is not Available

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I'm trying to run the following macro on a Mac Word document:

```
Sub AcceptDeletion()
    Dim oChange As Revision
    For Each oChange In ActiveDocument.Revisions
        With oChange
            If .Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
                .Accept
            End If
        End With
    Next oChange
End Sub
```

It is posted in this question: [Microsoft Word VBA script to accept all deletions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728454/microsoft-word-vba-script-to-accept-all-deletions)

It cleared several deleted revisions but then failed here:

```
If .Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
```

...with "Requested Object is not Available" run-time error (5852).

Any idea how to solve that?  I tried adding isMissing / IsError or to compare to Nothing as a safeguard without success.

Comment: You are modifying the Revisions collection while enumerating it, which is never a good idea. Try saving the revisions to an array first, or enumerating with `For` from `Revisions.Count to 1 step -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Following @GSerg answer, I modified the script as follows and it works:

```
Sub AcceptDeletions()
    Dim oChange As Revision
    For i = ActiveDocument.Revisions.Count To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
            ActiveDocument.Revisions(i).Accept
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```